# Error when using setup_postdata()

Tags: query

I am trying to get the most recent and show it using the native function (e.g. get_the_title()), do NOT want to use $post['post_title'] but when I do this I'm an error.

```
global $post;

$featured_post = wp_get_recent_posts(array( 'numberposts'=>'1', 'post_type' => 'post' ));

foreach ($featured_post as $post) {

    setup_postdata($post);  

    echo get_the_title();

}
```

This is the error I get:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /.../wp-includes/query.php on line 4601
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /.../wp-includes/query.php on line 4603
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /.../wp-includes/query.php on line 4605
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /.../wp-includes/query.php on line 4606
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /.../wp-includes/query.php on line 4617
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /.../wp-includes/query.php on line 4625
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /.../wp-includes/query.php on line 4642
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the error because, by default, [`wp_get_recent_posts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_recent_posts/) returns an array of posts (*due to backward compatibilty*) and not the required `WP_Post` object which is required to setup the template tags.

Look at the source code, and you will see that `wp_get_recent_posts` is a simple wrapper function for `get_posts` (*which is just a wrapper for `WP_Query`*). What makes the difference in output from `wp_get_recent_posts`, is the value of the it's second parameter, `$output` which is by default set to `ARRAY_A`. By default, the output from `get_posts` is converted to an array. Here is the piece of code responsible for that.

```
// Backward compatibility. Prior to 3.1 expected posts to be returned in array.
if ( ARRAY_A == $output ){
    foreach( $results as $key => $result ) {
        $results[$key] = get_object_vars( $result );
    }
    return $results ? $results : array();
}
```

To make your code work, simply pass an empty string (*or any crap for that matter*) to the second parameter of `wp_get_recent_posts` which will return the `WP_Post` object directly from `get_posts`

```
$featured_post = wp_get_recent_posts(array( 'numberposts'=>'1', 'post_type' => 'post' ), '');
```

or, for that matter

```
$featured_post = wp_get_recent_posts(array( 'numberposts'=>'1', 'post_type' => 'post' ), 'CRAP');
```

On final thing, simply use `the_title()` to display the title, no need for `echo get_the_title()`

### EDIT

Don't forget to call `wp_reset_postdata()` after your `foreach` loop

Comment: It's interesting to see that this `wp_get_recent_posts()l with it, since we could end up displaying draft or private posts.  hehe and we can even feed it with "crap" ;-)

Comment: @birgire Hahahaha, yes, a really crappy flaw ;-). I do however prefer `get_posts` above `wp_get_recent_posts`

Comment: oh somehow my comment is missing half of the text I wrote - but I agree  with you regarding the favorable `get_posts()`, since `wp_get_recent_posts()` uses even draft/private/... statuses by default   ;-)

Comment: `wp_get_recent_posts()` does support `OBJECT` as the second parameter but will still return *an Array* of objects.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee you can pass anything to the second parameter and it will return an object. As I said, even passing the word `crap` will return an object

Comment: @Howdy_McGee the word `OBJECT` is just to be fancy and really means nothing in this context